# The [proc-sql] tag is incorrectly used with Pro*C

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The `Proc*C` embedded C language [extends Oracle databases](https://www.google.com/search?q=proc-c).

The `PROC SQL` language [queries SAS data](https://www.google.com/search?q=procsql).

For some reason, the SO [proc-sql](/questions/tagged/proc-sql) tag covers `Proc*C` instead of `PROC SQL`.

I'm no expert on either technology, but it seems to me that a `Proc*C` tag should be created.  That would open up the `PROC-SQL` tag for SAS questions.

P.S. This meta question is a response to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087526/proc-sql-and-removing-duplicates-by-a-single-variable).

Comment: The embedded SQL pre-processor by Oracle is called Pro*C and **not** Proc*C!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the proc-sql tag has been used pretty much exclusively for SAS questions since it was first introduced.  Also, a large % of SAS questions do indeed relate to the 'sql procedure' (`proc sql;`)

So I'm going with the following 'answer' - YES, the proc-sql tag IS incorrectly used with Pro*C!

Comment: In that case, it's perhaps the tag wiki that is wrong

Comment: agreed, and I have proposed an update - which is awaiting review

Comment: Any way I could find your edit? When I search the review queue, it says: `There are no items for you to review, matching the filter "[proc-sql]"`

Comment: Hmm - I only did it earlier today, must have disappeared!  Have submitted a more detailed description now..

Comment: Approved your tag edit, and created a new `proc-c` tag!  If you find time to enrich the `proc-sql` tag with some example code and a link to SAS documentation that would be great.

Comment: Code examples and documentation links added :-)

Answer (score 2):

The embedded sql pre-processor by Oracle [is called Pro*C*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro*C) and **NOT** ProcC.

Thus, it is just plain wrong to introduce *proc-c* as new tag for Pro*C.

Unfortunately, the *proc-c* tag was already created - but no questions are tagged with it. It should be removed for the stated reasons.

Currently, there are 49 questions tagged with *proc-sql* and *oracle*.

On the other hand there are 45 questions tagged with *proc-sql* and *sas*.

Thus, the *proc-sql* tag is *NOT* exclusively used for SAS questions.

Looking at the revision history of the tag *proc-sql* the description is only about SAS usage - but when browsing the tag wiki, the old Oracle Pro*C info is displayed. Probably because of suggested edits.

A better alternative to resolve the proc-sql mess:

- introduce a new tag *pro-c* for Oracle Pro*C related questions (*proc* is already used for a Ruby construct of the same name, but *pro-c* is currently not in use)

Anyway, when doing such changes, the one doing them should also be responsible for migrating all the old Pro*C questions!

Comment: [pro-c] cannot be introduced, clashes with [proc]. I created  [oracle-pro-c] and started retagging.